# jQuery - Breakout game - Creating the blocks

Tags: jquery

I'm learning jQuery via the breakout game at Uni. I'm having trouble getting the multiple bricks to show up within the game. This is not homework, just me getting ahead of the in class exercises.

I'm trying to use the following loop to display the blocks.

```
for (var row = 0; row < 5; row++)
{
    for (var col = 0; col < 7; col++)
    {
        $("#game").append('<div class="brick" id="brick' + num + '"></div>');

        var brick = {x: col * 140, y: row * 60, id:"#brick" + num, alive:true};
        bricks.push(brick);

        num++;
    }
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tony_Edwards/PC4u9/) of complete code.

Comment: Do you have 'bricks' defined as an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give the bricks their x and y positions on the page as well, right now they're in the DOM but they're all in the same place. Try:

```
num = (row * 7) + col;
$brick = $('<div class="brick" id="brick' + num + '"></div>');
$brick.css({left: col * 140, right: row * 60});
$("#game").append($brick);
```

Notice I added code to increment the `num` value too.

You will need to make sure that you have this css too:

```
.brick{
    position: absolute;
}
```

Also, you need to define the array before you start adding to it, put this before the first loop:

```
bricks = [];
```

Comment: While correct, there are still exceptions thrown. It sounds like yours and Kevin's answers combined would be the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

The `.push()` function is called on an Array.  Within the code a bricks array does not exist.  Declare a bricks array and the code should push the new bricks onto the array.

Comment: While correct, only one brick appears. It sounds like yours and koosa's answers combined would be the correct answer.